# Parallel high speed and high current mosfets

Tags: mosfet, switching-regulator, gate-driving

In order to speed up switching times and reduce power (I2R) losses, is it worthwhile to put a fast switching (but high RDSon) FET in parallel with a low RDSon (but slow witching and high Qgs) FET? That way the fast FET handles the switching transition (but only for a few tens of nS) so the high current FET can be soft switched on and off at low loss for the remainder of the switching cycle. The two FETs would have their own gate drive circuits. Does anyone think this is a practical way to switch tens of amps at MHz speeds or should I just bite the bullet and go with the more expensive GaN FETs?

I managed to get a PSpice model of one of the FETs I was thinking of using, if I can push ~6A of gate drive into it, I can switch it in <3nS, I don't need the 1/2nS switching times of GaN FETs nor the headache of dealing with the EMI problems that would cause. The switching losses at 3nS should be manageable provided I can keep \$R_{\theta JA}\$ to less than 10 \$^{\circ}\$C/W.

Comment: Good idea, but expensive... Additional driver, additional mosfet, more space. But how much losses do you have? Or do you use that serial resistor on gate?

Comment: **IF** the arrangement is **DESIGNED** and the design shows it will work and it is cost effective for you then it's OK. The trap is that it is easy to implement systems such as this and overlook interactions which make it either harder or of low profit for effort. ie design it well frst. || FWIW as much lower frequencies this can work well with a MOSFET and a high current relay - especialy so at DC where arc breaking is a major factor in current ratings.

Comment: At high frequencies, capacitive switching losses dominate in MOSFETs, so lower Rds(on) will not help. This question http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/185721/how-to-achieve-the-max-efficiency-from-a-buck-converter/229486#229486 (specific to buck regulators but still appropriate) has the equations for losses in that application.

Comment: Interesting question, but I think hard to answer without your mentioning how many tens of amps, what will V_DS be, and which specific MOSFETs and driver you have in mind. My feeling is that it won't be worthwhile (or at least not worth the effort) in most cases, otherwise everyone would be doing it maybe special MOSFETs might exist to fill that niche. Perhaps your application is special in some way and it would be helpful, although based on your question it isn't possible to tell.

Comment: Thanks everyone. @PeterSmith I'd totally forgotten about the capacitive loss. That's going to be a real pain to deal with.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon It's difficult to model the inductances of the oddly shaped planes linking the Fet and the gate driver and it's hard to get reliable measurements on a test board without a GHz class oscilloscope - it's for an isolated DC-DC converter and the core losses in the transformer increase quickly at lower frequencies (only a few uH of primary inductance makes for a very low impedance). At a minimum this thing's going to be running at a little over a MHz and needs switching times on the order of 1-2nS to keep switching losses to manageable values. The BoM's still half that of GaN.

Comment: @GregoryKornblum total FET losses are hitting 5W or so according to Fairchild's loss spreadsheet, having two FETs will probably have more total losses but ideally less loss per fet as the thermal impedance of an SMD fet through a pcb to a heatsink is not amazingly good (Junction-Ambient is around 10'C/W). Adding a second fet and driver adds around an extra cm2 so space isn't an issue. To boost the gate drive current there is a small Pch (pull-down) and an Nch fet (pull-up) right at the gate connection to dump extra current into the gates to punch through the miller region.

Comment: @OleksandrR. I was going to be using an Infineon BSZ440N10NS3 as the high speed fet and an Infineon BSC097N06NSATMA1 as the high current fet, a Micrel MIC4604 as the gate driver with a Diodes Inc. ZXMC3AM832TA in parallel with the gate driver (and it's own bypass cap) to increase the initial pull-up and pull-down currents, the ZXMC3 supplies high initial current to get through the Miler region with the gate driver providing the last few volts to fully enhance the channel. But you are probably right, if it was likely to work, someone else would have probably already tried it.

Comment: Just FYI, the TI UCC27211 can sink/source 4A and has lower propagation delay than the MIC4604. It's a direct replacement, so you might be able to do away with your parallel ZXMC3AMC (N.B. ZXMC3AM832 is obsolete). I'm not sure that the difference in gate charge for your two proposed MOSFETs is big enough to make it worth the extra complication, quite honestly. You're already into the sub-2ns regime and will probably be limited by parasitic inductances (including bond wire inductance) more than anything else.

Comment: You should work out a possible design. I look up one of my design (600KHz), the estimates of power dissipation are (conduction loss 36%, capacitive loss 6%, crossover loss 57%). Obviously your design would be quite different (from your FET selections -> significantly higher current). With your proposed scheme, the combined conduction loss + crossover loss should reduce. The capacitive loss would go up, but if my numbers are typical, it has by far the smallest proportion.

Comment: @rioraxe for 57% of the switching loss to be due to cross-conduction seems excessive to me, considering that in principle this loss can be completely eliminated. Unless the total switching loss is negligibly small anyway, would it not be preferable to reduce this, even at the cost of slightly increasing the (absolute) capacitive dissipation by requiring faster switching?

Comment: I think you misunderstand what is crossover loss. It is not cross-conduction loss. For example, when a MOSFET turns off, the full inductor current keeps flowing through the MOSFET until it is almost fully off, that is part of the crossover loss. Both crossover loss and capacitive loss scale with switching frequency.

Comment: @rioraxe you are right; I had misunderstood the terminology. Thanks for the correction.